# What's the difference between long unsigned int and unsigned long int

Tags: c, types, syntax

Compiler is taking these two same.

`long unsigned int a;
 unsigned long int a;`

Comment: "Compiler is taking these two same." --> What did you expect?

Answer (score 5):

They **are** the same.

Quoting the `C11`, chapter §6.7.2, *Type specifiers*, (*emphasis mine*)

The list:

> *type-specifier:*
>
> `void`
>
> `char`
>
> `short`
>
> `int`
>
> `long`
>
> `float`
>
> `double`
>
> `signed`
>
> `unsigned`
>
> `_Bool`
>
> `_Complex`
>
> *atomic-type-specifier*
>
> *struct-or-union-specifier*
>
> *enum-specifier*
>
> *typedef-name*

and, P2,

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
>   and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
>   type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there
>   is more than one multiset per item); **the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.**

Comment: "The type specifiers may occur in any order " thanks for this line

Comment: @AmninderSingh That is why that is __emphasiszed.__ And these are **not** my own words, blatant copy direct from the C specs. Welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

No difference. Identical types.

Comment: very right, but some reference would be nice.